# trouble using an api on heroku from a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, heroku

for a project at school I am trying to use the Bandsintown api to display upcoming concerts for artists that a user follows on my site.  I am able to use the api the way I want to in development but when it comes to my heroku site in production nothing displays and I receive no errors, in fact I just receive an empty array.  Perhaps you need permission from Bandsintown to use their api on heroku?  I tried contacted them but have not heard a response yet.

My question, why am I able to get a response from Bandsintown on development but not in production?  New to web dev in general, so I haven't come across this before..

Here is my code:

calendar_controller.rb

```
class CalendarController < ApplicationController
  require 'uri'

  def index
    @user = current_user
    @hash_version_array = []

    @user.follows.each do |follow|
      response = HTTParty.get("http://api.bandsintown.com/artists/#{URI.escape(follow.artist_name)}/events/search.json?api_version=2.0&app_id=#{app_id}&location=use_geoip")
      @hash_version = JSON.parse(response.body)

      @hash_version_array << @hash_version if @hash_version != []
    end

    @hash_version_array
  end
end
```

calendar/index.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @user.name %>'s Calendar</h1>
<div>
  <h4 class="inline"><%= link_to "Calendar" %></h4>
  <h4 class="inline"><%= link_to "List" %></h4>
  <h4 class="inline"><%= link_to "Map" %></h4>
</div>
<br>

<% @hash_version_array.each do |date| %>
  <h3 class="artist_name"><%= date[0]["formatted_datetime"] %></h3>
  <% date[0]["artists"].each do |info| %>
    <h1 class="artist_name"><%= info["name"] %></h1>
    <br>
    <%= image_tag("#{info['thumb_url']}", class: 'artist_img') %>
  <% end %>

  <br>
  <br>

  <%= date[0]["venue"]["name"] %>
  <br>
  <%= date[0]["formatted_location"] %>, <%= date[0]["venue"]["country"] %>
  <br>
  Tickets <%= date[0]["ticket_status"].titleize %> <%= link_to("Buy", "#{date[0]['ticket_url']}") %>
  <br>
  <hr class="artists_hr">
<% end %>
```

Response from Bandsintown while working in development:

```
From: /Users/jasonquaccia/Sites/code/projects/capstone/the-music-project/app/controllers/calendar_controller.rb @ line 15 CalendarController#index:

     4: def index
     5:   @user = current_user
     6:   @hash_version_array = []
     7: 
     8:   @user.follows.each do |follow|
     9:     response = HTTParty.get("http://api.bandsintown.com/artists/#{URI.escape(follow.artist_name)}/events/search.json?api_version=2.0&app_id=el_proyecto_de_la_musica&location=use_geoip")
    10:     @hash_version = JSON.parse(response.body)
    11: 
    12:     @hash_version_array << @hash_version if @hash_version != []
    13:   end
    14: 
 => 15:   binding.pry
    16:   @hash_version_array
    17: end

[1] pry(#<CalendarController>)> @hash_version_array
=> [[{"id"=>10847723,
   "title"=>"Metallica @ AT & T Park in San Francisco, CA",
   "datetime"=>"2016-02-06T19:00:00",
   "formatted_datetime"=>"Saturday, February 6, 2016 at 7:00PM",
   "formatted_location"=>"San Francisco, CA",
   "ticket_url"=>"http://www.bandsintown.com/event/10847723/buy_tickets?app_id=el_proyecto_de_la_musica&artist=Metallica&came_from=67",
   "ticket_type"=>"Tickets",
   "ticket_status"=>"available",
   "on_sale_datetime"=>"2015-11-06T10:00:00",
   "facebook_rsvp_url"=>"http://www.bandsintown.com/event/10847723?app_id=el_proyecto_de_la_musica&artist=Metallica&came_from=67",
   "description"=>"CBS RADIO&#39;s The Night Before with Metallica and Cage the Elephant",
   "artists"=>
    [{"name"=>"Metallica",
      "mbid"=>"65f4f0c5-ef9e-490c-aee3-909e7ae6b2ab",
      "image_url"=>"https://s3.amazonaws.com/bit-photos/large/4304043.jpeg",
      "thumb_url"=>"https://s3.amazonaws.com/bit-photos/thumb/4304043.jpeg",
      "facebook_tour_dates_url"=>"http://www.bandsintown.com/Metallica/facebookapp?came_from=67",
      "facebook_page_url"=>nil,
      "tracker_count"=>2341049,
      "url"=>"Metallica",
      "website"=>"http://metallica.com"}],
   "venue"=>{"name"=>"AT & T Park", "city"=>"San Francisco",     "region"=>"CA", "country"=>"United States", "latitude"=>37.7784059, "longitude"=>-122.3894401}}]]
```

Comment: the pry output is production? because it's not empty at all, if it is maybe this is deployment issue we need more details if so.(this is not API issue because it worked for me without any problem )

Comment: apologize, i meant to put development not production for that pry output.  Made an edit.  Also I was able to figure out what the problem was, see answer..

Answer (score 0):

Found out why I am not getting anything while in production on Heroku, has to do with `location=use_geoip` on this line:

```
response = HTTParty.get("http://api.bandsintown.com/artists/#{URI.escape(follow.artist_name)}/events/search.json?api_version=2.0&app_id=#{app_id}&location=use_geoip")
```

This works locally because it can reference my location and then search Bandsintown for the correct information.  However, on Heroku it does not know how to correctly reference a location.  Therefore I don't receive any results.